# Custom api development with magento not working in server

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, soap-api-v2

Just using following tutorials created custom api in magento and working properly in local host 

http://easyway2magento.blogspot.in/2015/04/magento-custom-api-method-to-login-as.html
But when we push this code into server and run api call according to documentation.

Its give fatal error:

 
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [3] Invalid api path. in /API2_DEV/apicall.php:7 

Stack trace: #0 /API2_DEV/apicall.php(7): SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 /API2_DEV/apicall.php(7): SoapClient->call('cb12be9e72de1f1...', 'fcustomer.check...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /API2_DEV/apicall.php on line 7

Please help me i am  stuck here .

Comment: can you share your api url?

Comment: custom methods : tokenbaseGetCard, tokenbaseGetCardsByCustomer, tokenbaseDeleteCard & tokenbaseUpdateCard right?

Comment: No , we are looking on customer login  using custom api.
and also product list ,both are working properly in local but not working in server.

Comment: are calling api with url : http://52.10.202.42/LL_API2_DEV/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

Comment: When using  above url got following error  Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("call") is not a valid method for this service in

Comment: can you share code from file apicall.php ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got the solution.
Have problem in api.xml and wsdl.xml files. some tags  names are mismatched .
cache also problem here. delete cache from magento.
For cache path magento/var/cache

thanks.